# How can I access the window menu for a VirtualBox VM in XFCE

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, window-manager, xfce

I'm running XFCE on Linux and using VirtualBox. When I start a VM, I'd like to be able to access the XFCE window menu on the VM itself in order to set the window mode to sticky ("Always on Visible Workspace"). However when I click on the upper left hand icon to access the window, nothing happens. Also, when I highlight the title bar of the window and try to use the hotkey I've setup to set a window as sticky (Super+s), the keystroke is sent to the guest VM, not to the window manager of the host.  How can I set the Guest VM's window on the host to sticky mode?

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the host key (Right Ctrl by default I think) will change the context of where the keyboard keystrokes are being sent and also allow you to open the Host XFCE window menu for the Guest VM.  Just press Right Ctrl once and you should see the VirtualBox down arrow icon in the bottom right of the window change color and then click on the XFCE window menu.

Comment: don't forget to mark this answer as accepted

Comment: I have to wait two days before I can accept my own answer